# How do i make virtual machine work on a old computer?

Tags: virtual-machine

i have an old computer and want to get vm on it.
what ever program i try to use(vmwere, VirtualBox..) it says it isent compatible.
dose anyone know of a systam that works for old computers?
this is my device specifications:

Device name Computer
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8400  @ 3.00GHz   3.00 GHz
Installed RAM   8.00 GB (7.81 GB usable)
Device ID
Product ID
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Windows 10 Pro

thanks

Comment: I wa surprised that this CPU dors have vt-x extensions (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/33910/intel-core2-duo-processor-e8400-6m-cache-3-00-ghz-1333-mhz-fsb.html) so it may not be impossible.  Have you gone to your BIOS and checked if 5here is an option to enable support for Virtualization?

Comment: Also try an older version of VMware (V12 or a bit later).

Comment: Download and run this app, see that is says about your hardware virtualization>>>>https://www.grc.com/securable.htm

Comment: Normally hardware virtualization is disabled in the bios on most computers